# SQL Statement with Select Atleast Two

Tags: sql

`state(code, name, country, population)
statelanguage(statecode, statelanguage, isofficial, percentage)`

In table state, code refers to the code of a state, the rest of the attributes are trivial. In table statelanguage, statecode refers the code for a particular state, statelanguage is a language that is spoken in this state, isofficial is a boolean on whether this language is the states official langauge and percentage is the percentage of people who speak the state language.

What I am trying to do is write an SQL statement to select the statecode where atleast two different languages are spoken.

My idea was to first get the statecode for the states that speak only 1 language then subtract this from the original table and project only the statecode. But I am struggling on how to do this.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregate function to count languages for each state:

```
   select statecode, count(distinct statelanguage)
   from statelanguage 
   group by statecode
```

Now limit the states with a `HAVING`

```
   select statecode, count(distinct statelanguage)
   from statelanguage 
   group by statecode
   having count(distinct statelanguage) >=2
```

Comment: Thanks for that I'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
  from state
 where ( select count(distinct statelanguage)
           from statelanguage
          where statecode = state.code ) >= 2
```